# Can I lower the video quality settings using some extra configuration?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-2

I lowered everything in the default options section of the game.

Is there a way to lower them even further? Like a console command, or even configuring a file?

Answer (score 2):

Mass Effect 2 is based on Unreal Engine 3, which allows for quite a lot of tweaking. See [this page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_2%29) for a number of suggestions. Also, since Mass Effect 2 uses the same engine as Mass Effect you could check this excellent tweaking guide (aimed at performance) from [Tweakguides](http://www.tweakguides.com/ME_1.html).

Comment: Which is kinda amazing if you think about it. ME2 is *so* much prettier than ME1.

Answer (score 0):

In your video card settings, you can set the Direct3D (or simply 3D) settings lower, or further towards "Performance."